# Json get request show in list view using base adapter

Tags: json, listview, http, get

I want to get Json parse data using get request show in list view and when user clicked on an item so in another activity.

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```